# Smooth Scroll for GridView

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, position, smooth-scrolling

Does `smoothScrollToPosition()` method for `GridView` works correctly?
I have found an open [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13385) and mine is not working correctly either.

`setSelection()` is working fine but I want a smooth scroll effect.

Do you have any idea about this issue?

If this is a persistent problem, where should I start to implement a good scroll effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I'm not seeing any issues running the example code you posted, if you're not seeing consistent results in your application it's not too tricky to create your own scroll controller.  Here's an example implementation you could use:

```
private class ScrollPositioner {
    private static final int SCROLL_DURATION = 20;
    private static final int DIR_UP = 1;
    private static final int DIR_DOWN = 2;

    int mTargetPosition = AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION;
    int mDirection = AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION;
    int mLastSeenPosition = AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION;
    int mExtraScroll;
    GridView mGrid;

    public ScrollPositioner(GridView grid) {
        mGrid = grid;
        mExtraScroll = ViewConfiguration.get(mGrid.getContext()).getScaledFadingEdgeLength();
    }

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mScroller = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int firstPos = mGrid.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            switch(mDirection) {
            case DIR_UP: {
                if (firstPos == mLastSeenPosition) {
                    // No new views, let things keep going.
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mScroller, SCROLL_DURATION);
                    return;
                }

                final View firstView = mGrid.getChildAt(0);
                if (firstView == null) {
                    return;
                }
                final int firstViewTop = firstView.getTop();
                final int extraScroll = firstPos > 0 ? mExtraScroll : mGrid.getPaddingTop();

                mGrid.smoothScrollBy(firstViewTop - extraScroll, SCROLL_DURATION);

                mLastSeenPosition = firstPos;

                if (firstPos > mTargetPosition) {
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mScroller, SCROLL_DURATION);
                }
                break;
            }

            case DIR_DOWN: {
                final int lastViewIndex = mGrid.getChildCount() - 1;
                final int lastPos = firstPos + lastViewIndex;

                if (lastViewIndex < 0) {
                    return;
                }

                if (lastPos == mLastSeenPosition) {
                    // No new views, let things keep going.
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mScroller, SCROLL_DURATION);
                    return;
                }

                final View lastView = mGrid.getChildAt(lastViewIndex);
                final int lastViewHeight = lastView.getHeight();
                final int lastViewTop = lastView.getTop();
                final int lastViewPixelsShowing = mGrid.getHeight() - lastViewTop;
                final int extraScroll = lastPos < mGrid.getAdapter().getCount() - 1 ? mExtraScroll : mGrid.getPaddingBottom();

                mGrid.smoothScrollBy(lastViewHeight - lastViewPixelsShowing + extraScroll, SCROLL_DURATION);

                mLastSeenPosition = lastPos;
                if (lastPos < mTargetPosition) {
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mScroller, SCROLL_DURATION);
                }
                break;
            }

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    public void scrollToPosition(int position) {
        mTargetPosition = position;
        mLastSeenPosition = AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION;

        if(position < mGrid.getFirstVisiblePosition()) {
            mDirection = DIR_UP;
        } else if (position > mGrid.getLastVisiblePosition()) {
            mDirection = DIR_DOWN;
        } else {
            return;
        }
        mHandler.post(mScroller);
    }
}
```

Here's a snippet from the example you linked that includes where this new class to do the scrolling in place of the framework implementation:

```
GridView g;
boolean t= false;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Instantiate and attach the custom positioner
    if(mPositioner == null) {
        mPositioner = new ScrollPositioner(g);
    }
    //Use the custom object to scroll the view
    mPositioner.scrollToPosition(0);
    if(t) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else {
        t = true;
    }
}
```

If you want to add a feature where the selected position is always scrolled to the top even when the scrolling direction is down, you could do that.  **This is not something the framework's implementation is designed to do**, but you could accomplish it by adding some code in `DIR_DOWN` to continue scrolling until the first visible position matches target (like `DIR_UP` does).  You must also beware of the case where the scrolling ends before the position reaches the top, so you aren't constantly posting the handler in cases where you will never get a different result.

HTH

Comment: This was really helpful I have also examined the implementation of the PositionScroller in AbsListview here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/AbsListView.java?av=f#3883 which is the super class of GridView but I was not able to trim the code to use it in my project. This snippet of yours is really helpful. However, how can I make the scrolled position to appear at the top of the gridview. Because with this implementatin scroll stops as soon as the item enters the view so it does not fully displayed.

Comment: I modified my example based on the framework implementation so that the items will fully scroll on-screen instead of stopping as soon as they are visible, which clips them behind the fading edge, and added some notes.

Comment: Proposed class leaks memory with reference to GridView

Comment: @AnatoliyShuba There would only be a memory leak if the Handler being used in the positioner were triggering all the time, which would attach the entire object graph to a running thread. Simply allowing two objects owned by the same Activity to reference each other is not a memory leak.

Comment: This certainly sheds a lot of light on how the OS works, but as a consumer of it's API I'm not particularly interested in spending the time to learn it, nor should I be exposed to such implementation details (ideally anyway). The API should provide all the functionality needed, with method names that sufficiently describe the expected behavior. It's no different than a processors ISA (if an instruction's named crossproduct, I expect one). Thanks though, this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue- I built a simple GridView and for some reason the `smoothScrollToPosition()` didn't work at all (just bounce from time to time).

after lot of debugging it turn out to be that I need to remove the `android:padding` parameter from the GridView.

very strange, I really don't know why it is like this, but at least now it works.

Comment: It needs to be trimmed from before calling `mGrid.smoothScrollBy()`. So `mGrid.smoothScrollBy(lastViewHeight - lastViewPixelsShowing + extraScroll, SCROLL_DURATION)` becomes `mGrid.smoothScrollBy(lastViewHeight - lastViewPixelsShowing + extraScroll - grid.getListPaddingTop(), SCROLL_DURATION)` for some reason the bottom padding doesn't.