# Get access of gridview from its adapter- Android

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, smooth-scrolling

I have a custom `gridview` with my own adapter.I'm handling `gridview` button click at adapter's implementation.After pressing the button I want to show a quick actionbar like "confirm" then if the user press on the confirm action then the gridview automatically smoothscroll to another position.This is what I want. Now I have created the quick actionbar successfully but i dont know how to implement the smoothscroll.

Comment: Do you want to get Access to your gridview from adapter or you want to implement smooth scroll.?

Comment: yes that is what i really wants

Comment: refer my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `getView` use

```
GridView gv=(GridView)parent;
```

To get gridView

***Edit***

Run smooth scroll with a delay

```
gridView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                gridView.smoothScrollBy(1000, 10000);
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: Make sure that you dont have any padding in grid view

Comment: some times with padding smoothScrollBy doest works.... For you nothing is happening right?

Comment: Here is the solution  Use Edit

Comment: gridView.smoothScrollBy(distance , duration);  distance:Distance to scroll in pixels.
    duration:Duration of the scroll animation in milliseconds.

Comment: Positive distance  Scroll down, Negative up

Comment: public AdapterGridView(Context c, TextView txt) {
   mContext = c;
   textViewInAdp = txt;
  }   Do like this in constructor of Adapter and call this Adapter from main view  using object of textview

Comment: Ya i thin then you have to dynamically add it to common layout. its my   id arun.cthomas3@gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

> To access GridView in your Adapter class, you could use Arun's answer:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ....
     GridView gv = (GridView)parent;

}
```

> To implement smooth scrolling check this answer:
>   [Smooth Scrolling implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8922824/1567588)

Answer (score 0):

parentIn my case GridItemClickListner didn't worked for some reason. I access the **Gridview from Adapter class** using this

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          ((GridView) v.getParent()).performItemClick(v, position, v.getId());
                         (OR)
          ((GridView)parent).performItemClick(v, position, v.getId());
   }
 });
}
```