# smoothScrollToPosition Not Working-Android GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-listview, android-gridview

I have a `GridView` with 10 rows and 10 columns.When the activity starts the `GridView` scroll to the last position then I can select an item from last row after selecting the item from last row it will scroll to second last row..etc.But my `smoothscrollToPosition` not working(just bounce from time to time) So I have done this `gridView.smoothScrollBy(-63,1000)` But I am not getting a good result because this scrolling has not a uniform position for every phones.So what I have to do for getting a uniform scrolling for every phones.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using **gv.smoothScrollBy()** try using **gv.smoothScrollTo()** and mention the specific position where you want it to show because scrollBy will scroll by that many pixels instead of pointing to that particular position.

And also see, if the values you provided are not in the bounds of screen, then it will start showing weird results, happens generally when you are trying out different device having different screen size and the pixels mentioned by you doesn't exist in visible area. For that try using:

```
private int getVisibleArea()
{
    int measureValue = 0;
    switch (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
        measureValue =(screenHeight);
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
        measureValue = (screenHeight);
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
        measureValue = (screenHeight);
        break;
    }
    return measureValue;
}
```

where screenHeight is:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            screenHeight = display.getHeight();
```

Comment: @ abhy where should i add this code.? and I couldnt find that function gv.smoothScrollTo() I am using android 2.2

Comment: smoothscrollToPosition is not working just bouncing the grid when we call smoothscrollToposition

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628106/android-gridview-smoothscroll-doesnt-work-just-bounce-from-time-to-time this is what i need ..I am stuck at my last milestone

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I handled similar situation when I was facing scrollview and also I verified no such method smoothScrollTo() is present in GridView, rather you may want to go with the method smoothScrollToPosition(position, boundPosition), that will help you out. Moreover before proceeding just read out this thread too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903212/smooth-scroll-for-gridview This will give you a clear idea how to stop bouncing. And it will be more helpful if you tell what you are trying to achieve, so that any other workaround is suggested.